# Graph Api - events how to specify date range. Not getting recurring events

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am specifying

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me//events?filter=start/DateTime ge '2021-03-02T19:30' and 
start/DateTime lt '2021-03-03T20:00'
```

I am not getting recurring events when specifying the range. Any specific reason? I need events for a day

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events` returns only single instance and master series.

If you know id of recurring event you can use the following endpoint to get the instances (occurrences) of an event for a specified time range.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{event_id}/instances?startDateTime=2021-03-02T19:30:00.0000000&endDateTime=22021-03-03T20:00.0000000
```

[List instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-list-instances?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: How to get events occuring in a day?

Comment: I dont have event id.. i am trying to fetch all meetings in a day

Answer (score 0):

What I did was fetched all master events for the past year and then looped on that to get instances that occur during the date range.
It is a huge PITA for what you get out of it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. To start with, recurring events have a master event that you should see in the response of the endpoint, and then use the event instances endpoint to bring the occurrences of the event series. It's very likely that the date range you used in the filter does not contain the master event, as it may have a date from earlier than what you are searching for. If you don't know, like me, on what date to search, I recommend filtering the event search by type eq 'seriesMaster'.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a couple years old, but in case anyone else stumbles across this like I did, you can get events in a `calendarView`.  Per the documentation, this includes "...occurrences, exceptions, and single instances of events in a calendar view defined by a time range..."

Example:

```
GET /me/calendar/calendarView?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}
```

In my case some holidays on my holiday calendar, like Christmas, were recurring, while others were not.  Using the view solved OP's issue of not getting instances of a master event within the specified time range in the API response.

You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-calendarview